# Web cam issues with jquery webcam in Internet Explorer

Tags: jquery, webcam, jquery-webcam-plugin

Hi i have just installed a webcam and also have done the code for the same as of the following website http://www.xarg.org/project/jquery-webcam-plugin/ .Now the issue i am having is when i open up this website in mozilla i am able to see the pic and capture it, this also works in chrome, however it doesnt work in Internet Explorer i just see an x mark and do not see the image at all, i am using i.e. 8 and have installed the latest flash player on it still no luck. please let me know if i am missing something?

I do have the latest Flash Player installed in i.e. and have given the allow access as well for the web cam it captures the picture but doesnt display it in the box below, and instead throws a javascript error which says object doesnt support this property or method, but works perfectly fine with firefox and chrome, it takes the pic and puts it in the box below, do i need to install any other addons for this?

Comment: Have you installed the Flash plugin for IE and given it access to your webcam?

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you have to install and enable the "Shockwave flash object"
IE->settings-> Internet Option-> Programs-> Manage Add-ons-> Shockwave flash object.
This is will in chrome/Edge